# Controlling the number of significant digits in a pyplot-label

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

If I've got a plot with some data points, where I have calculated a certain χ^2_min value, and I want that value to be displayed, how do I indicate how many significant digits are to be shown?

For example, I made this random script to test it out:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = np.array([1.0, 5.0, 10, 20, 50])
ys = np.array([10, 50, 200, 250, 300])
y_err = 20
chi2min = 123

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.errorbar(xs, ys, y_err, color = 'tab:blue', fmt = 'o', ms = 5, capsize=4, label = r'$\chi^2_{min}$ = 'f'{chi2min:.1f}')
ax.legend()
```

The f-thing, we were tought in class, apparently only controls the number of decimals - how do I round down to 2 digits and make python display χ^2_min = 1.2e+01?

**EDIT**: I've found out how to do it with one number, but what if I've got multiple values, I want to be shown with two significant digits in a loop? Fx:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = np.array([1.0, 5.0, 10, 20, 50])
ys = np.array([10, 50, 200, 250, 300])
y_err = 20
chi2mins = [123, 80]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize = (12, 12))
for ax, chi2min in zip(axs, chi2mins):
    ax.errorbar(xs, ys, y_err, color = 'tab:blue', fmt = 'o', ms = 5, capsize=4, label = r'$\chi^2_{min}$ = 'f'{chi2min:.1f}')
    ax.legend()
```

How do I round down to 2 digits and make python display χ^2_min = 1.2e+02 on the first plot and χ^2_min = 80 on the second?

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
label = r'$\chi^2_{min}$ = 'f'{chi2min:.1f}'
```

With:

```
label = r'$\chi^2_{min}$ = 'f'{0.1*chi2min:.1e}'
```

[image]

**Update**

```
...
for ax, chi2min in zip(axs, chi2mins):
    chi2min = f'{chi2min:.1e}' if isinstance(chi2min, float) or chi2min >= 100 else str(chi2min)
    ax.errorbar(xs, ys, y_err, color = 'tab:blue', fmt = 'o', ms = 5, capsize=4, label = r'$\chi^2_{min}$ = 'f'{chi2min}')
    ax.legend()
```

Comment: Thanks man. Do you know a solution to my 'extended problem'? :))

Comment: If chi2min is 85, what should be the output?

Comment: Just 85. Two significant digits :)
And if it is 7.397, it should be 7.4

Comment: 7.4 but you want to display 7.4e+01? So why not 12.3e+01? I think I missed something

Comment: Not exactly, 7.4e+01 = 74 ;)
Whatever the chi2min-value is, it should be displayed in the plot with 2 significant digits. Such as if chi2min = 12345 should be shown with scientific notation as as 1.2e+04, chi2min = 123 shown as 1.2e+02, chi2min = 31 as 31 (that's already 2 significant digits), chi2min = 7.1234 as 7.1, 2 significant digits again, and chi2min = 0.087 is shown as 8.7e-02, ect. :)

Comment: Can you try `[f'{n:.1e}' if isinstance(n, float) or n >= 100 else n for n in chi2mins]`?

Comment: I get "invalid syntax" error around the "else n for n in chi2mins" :((

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?